# Mini- Cooper 2002 squealing noise, burning smell, hot rear wheel

Tags: brake-rotor

I have a Mini Cooper; I’ve noticed recently a squealing noise coming from the rear wheel on the drivers side. The squealing noise happens when the brakes are not applied. I touched the rotor and it burned me. I tried the other wheels and they weren't hot at all.

The calipers, rotors, and the wheel itself are extremely hot. It also has a very bitter burning smell.
I’ve recently had new brakes and new calipers put on the rear wheels 
What do you think the problem is? 
Thanks.

Comment: "I’ve recently had new brakes and new calipers put on rear wheels " faulty parts or installation.

Answer (score 1):

It all sounds a stuck brake caliper. Go straight back to the person or garage that did your brakes because it seems they made some mistakes in installing the new brake components.

Comment: it may not be their fault, sometimes a caliper is fine until you push the piston back in during a brake job, no way to know if it will freeze up at a later date when the piston moves back out.